How to reduce number of notification banners/popups from Outlook?
I usually leave my laptop running over night, with the lid closed.
When I resume working on it the next day, there are typically a coupled dozen new emails.
For every single email, Outlook sends a notification to the Windows 11 notifications center. So I get 30-50 notifications after opening my PC. This is extremely annoying and pointless - I am already aware that there are many new emails, a single "You have 50 new emails" notification would make a lot more sense.
During the day, however, it's of course perfectly fine to receive a separate notification for each email.
Is there a way to avoid this? Or do I just have to turn off notifications from Outlook altogether?
I also use Thunderbird and changed its settings to use its own notifications instead of Windows notifications, which solved the issue for that application at least...

You can just close outlook at night and restart it in the morning. If many emails come in together, they are grouped as one notification, but if outlook is running, each email is received individually. Also, from the notifications in Action Center, there's a button that will say, mark all as read.

Not sure about Outlook, but Thunderbird email client gives a choice of visual notification and/or sound played for new message, and likely Outlook does, also. Just turn off popups and use the system sound.

I asked a simple question - Windows should understand it’s not very useful to display “toast” popups from the same application for 1-2 minutes straight. It’s extremely annoying. That doesn’t mean I want to disable them, I just don’t want to see dozens of them. Windows could show 2-3 and then refer the user to the notification area for the rest. But this is not possible? Absolutely crazy. Who does their UX design?

By default, Desktop Alerts are turned on.
If you want to turn alerts off, refer to these steps:
Select File.
Select Options, then Mail.
Under Message arrival, select to clear Display a Desktop Alert check box, and then select OK.

But I don’t want to turn off alerts. Please read my question.
